# "maximum recursion depth exceeded" after concatenating and comparing 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

So I was playing with the `concat` method:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( data=randn(5,1), index=range(5) )
df2 = pd.DataFrame( data=randn(5,1), index=range(5) )
df12 = pd.concat( [ df1, df2 ], axis=1 )
df34 = pd.concat( [ df1.T, df2.T ], axis=0 )
```

Then I did

```
( df12.T == df34 ).all()
```

and got a series of `True` as expected. But then I tried this:

```
( df12 == df34.T ).all()
```

I was expecting `True` but I got this:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
```

Any help is welcome. I am using Mac OSX, python 2.7.5, numpy 1.7.1, pandas 0.12.0

Comment: What version python, pandas and numpy are you using? This works for me using python 3.3 64-bit, pandas 0.13.1 and numpy 1.8.0

Comment: Could be a bug, are you able to upgrade pandas and numpy?

Comment: Upgrading to pandas 0.13.1 did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: It is more likely that this was fixed in [0.13.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/release.html#release-bug-fixes-0-13-0) than [0.13.1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/release.html#release-bug-fixes-0-13-1) judging by the longer list of bug-fixes but I cannot identify which one could've fixed this